# Find Second Sunday of every May, depending on the year

Tags: javascript, date

```
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setFullYear(year);
        myDate.setMonth(4);
        myDate.setDate(1);

if (myDate.getDay() == 0) {
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);
}
else {
    var daysUntilFirstSunday =  myDate.getDay() % 7;
    var firstSunday = myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + daysUntilFirstSunday);
    var secondSunday = myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 7);
}
```

Trying to pinpoint what is wrong with my if else statement since the dates are off

Comment: In JS months start at 0, so May is 4, not 5.

Comment: You might find some value in [Date.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation).

Comment: Or my favorite, [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: maybe using a whole date library for a single issue is an overkill...

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
function getMothersDay (year) {
    var date = new Date(year, 4, 7);
    date.setDate(7 + (7 - date.getDay()));
    return date;
}
```

It's been fully tested and works perfectly. It's faster than most of the alternatives here, since it only makes one `Date` instance and re-uses it. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WCMX8/1/).

Comment: This doesn’t work, you forgot parentheses. In JS, `+` has a higher precedence than the tertiary operator, `a+b?c:d` is equivalent to `(a+b)?c:d`. Add parentheses around the second part of the addition line 3 to fix this issue. Also, you can replace `date.getDate()` with `1`, it’s *always* `1` because you set it the line before.

Comment: @bfontaine Working perfectly now (compared to Google result for `mother's day <year>`.

Comment: @rvighne Can you please explain the logic behind the math? Otherwise there's a taste of copy here...

Comment: @Teemu Of course. First line, I create a Date instance for the seventh of May. That's the earliest possible Mother's Day and guaranteed to be on or past the first Sunday. Then I add the number of days it is to the next Sunday. This works because (if it's Sunday on the seventh) Sunday is zero and subtracting that from 7 gives 7, so one week. And a week from Sunday is Sunday. By that same logic (for all the other days) that expression gives the closest Sunday from the seventh. Okay? I swear I didn't copy a drop from your code.

Comment: @rvighne "Date instance for the seventh of May. That's the earliest possible Mother's Day". That is incorrect, its impossible for the 7th to ever be the second Sunday. Your logic may produce the correct result, but you are not explaining (or understanding?) it properly. The 7th is the DAY BEFORE the earliest possible Mothers Day.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
function getMotherDayDate(year) {
    var start = new Date(year, 4, 7),
        secondSunday = 7 + (7 - start.getDay());
    return new Date(year, 4, secondSunday); 
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vB94/).

---

**EDIT**

To answer your edited question: You're just adding `7 + myDate.getDay()` to the current date of `myDate`, since the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) in `myDate.getDay() % 7` just returns `myDate.getDay()` when `myDate.getDay() < 7`.

Please feel free to use the snippet above. You can check more Mom's Day dates at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vB94/1/).